# Auto implemented properties default value in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Properties

```
 public class student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public mark mark { get; set; }
}
public class mark
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm creating object as below

```
student x=new student();
x.id=1 --> default value 0
```

but when i access **x.mark.value** it throwing exception(x.mark is null)

Doesn't initiate by default? any reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value for an automatic property is `default(T)`, where `T` is the type.  Since the default for any reference type is `null`, `mark` is null.  Value types can never be null and, as you have noticed, `default(int)` is `0`.

Comment: @balaji: I don't know what you mean by that, but typically you would *construct* your type in your *constructor*, i.e., `mark = new mark();`

Comment: Value types can be set to null if required Forexample Nullable<int> or int?

Comment: @slashshogdhe: Value types can *never* be null.  You can of course create a wrapper with properly overloaded operators to simulate such a thing.  Just because `Nullable<T>` exists for such a purpose doesn't mean you are actually setting a value type to `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Default value for all reference types is **null** not 0. You should initialize it in your constructor:

```
public student()
{
   mark = new mark();
}
```

When you try to access `mark.value` without initializing it you are trying to access a `null object's property` which is cause the `NullReferenceException`:

```
null.value = NullReferenceException!
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  and this question for more details: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

class is reference type, and all reference types resides in heap, their memory is allocated when you create object of it using new. So if you doesn't create new object i.e. you don't instantiate that class it will hold null i.e. no address is assigned to that class.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in C# automatically take on their default values (which can be found by calling `default` on them - for example `default(int)`.

The reason your ID variable is being intialised to zero is because the default of an int is 0.

The reason your Mark variable is being intialised to nullis because the default of any class is null.

Answer (score 0):

*Default value* for reference types is null reference. Make your `mark` a struct if you want the behavior you described:

```
public struct mark
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}

student x = new student();
x.id = 1;
x.mark.value = 5; // No exception thrown
```

As an alternative, just `new` your `mark` from within the constructor:

```
public student()
{
    this.mark = new mark();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the object instance mark which you do not initialize in your student class.
There are many options available for you. If you insist that they both should be classes, create a instance of Mark in default constructor of Student

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.mark = new Mark();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public Mark mark { get; set; }
}
public class Mark
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you don't see, i guess, is that you are initializing student in fact, but not mark at all!
While initializing student by using

```
student s = new student();
s.id = 1;
```

All your properties would look like this:

- id = 1
- mark = null

If you would extend your constructor for student-class like this:

```
public class student
{
    public student() {
        this.mark = new mark();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public mark mark { get; set; }
}
```

You would reach your goal for a default value of 0 when calling

```
x.mark.value;
```

while your properties would look like this:

- id = 1
- mark = 0

i hope this might help you!